# How do I add a .so file to my apk files in order for the script to run on app boot?

Tags: javascript, apk, decompiling

I have my businesses apk and apk decompiled files and I would like to add a .so file to my decompiled files in order for a script to run on start. Can someone help me?

I tried looking in the lib folder but I couldn’t find where to add it. Can someone show me where I would put this.